# Merging/Sorting My Array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, merge

What I need to do is ask the user to input values for two arrays and then output them separately and also output a merged array that is in ascending order.

For example, if the user inputs 2,5,8,0 for the first array and 6,7,0 for the second array, then the merged array should output 2,5,6,7,8.

The output for my first two arrays work perfectly but the merged array always outputs a zero. I also added a restart boolean to see if the user wants to try it again. Please help me as I am stuck.

I understand the though process but not sure how to implement this into my code. Here is my code:

```
//import packages
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math; 
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main4{

public static void main(String[] args){

boolean doItAgain = true;//add boolean value to use when restarting progam

Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);//initialize new scanner

while(doItAgain){

//initialize variables
int first [] = new int[10000];//initialize to maximum of 10,000 integers
int second [] = new int[10000];//initialize to maximum of 10,000 integers
int input1; 
int input2; 
int counter1 = 0;//counter variable for first string
int counter2 = 0;//counter variable for second string


System.out.println("");
System.out.println("Welcome To my Merge Array Program 2.0!");
System.out.println("Enter the values for the first array, up to 10000 values, enter zero or a negative number to quit"); //asks user for first array input

//loop to go through each index
for (int a = 0; a<10000; a++) 
{ 
  input1 = scan.nextInt();//stores input as input1
  first [a] = input1; 
  counter1++; 
  if (input1<=0)
    break;//breaks out of loop if input1 value is 0 or below
}

int first2 []= new int [counter1-1]; 
for(int b = 0; b<first2.length; b++) { 
  first2 [b] = first[b]; 
} 


System.out.println("Enter the values for the second array, up to 10000 values, enter zero or a negative number to quit"); //asks user for second array input

for (int j = 0; j<10000; j++)
{ 
  input2 = scan.nextInt();//stores input as input2
  second [j] = input2; 
  counter2++;
  if (input2<=0)
    break;//breaks out of loop if input1 value is 0 or below
}

int second2 []= new int [counter2-1]; 
for(int c = 0; c<second2.length; c++) { 
  second2 [c] = second[c]; 
} 

System.out.println("First Array:");//output first array values in the order of their input
for (int p=0; p<first2.length; p++) {
  System.out.print(first2[p] + " "); 
}
  System.out.println("\nSecond Array:");//output second array values in the order of their input
  for (int p2=0; p2<second2.length;p2++) { 
    System.out.print(second2[p2] + " "); 
  } 

  boolean valid = true; 
  for (int e = 0; e<first2.length-1; e++) { 
    if(first2[e]>first2[e+1]) { 
      valid = false; 
    }

  } 
  for (int e2 = 0; e2<second2.length-1;e2++) { 
    if(second2[e2]>second2[e2+1]) { 
      valid = false;
    } 
  }


  int[] array = new int[first2.length + second2.length];

  //fill array 3 with arrays 1 & 2
  for(int k = 0; k <first2.length;k++){
    array[k] = first2[k];
  }

  for (int l = 0; l<second2.length; l++){
    array[first2.length + l] = second2[l];
  }

  //sort array 3
  for (int i = 0; i<first2.length + 1; i++){
    for (int j = i+1; j<first2.length + 1; j++){

      if(array[i] > array[j]){
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }

  //output sorted merged array
  System.out.println("\nMerged Array: ");
  for(int p3 = 0; p3<array.length; p3++) {
    System.out.print(array[p3] + " "); 
  }

  //Asks user if they want to restart program. Used boolean value to initialize doItAgain variable
  System.out.println("");
  System.out.println("");
  System.out.println("Thanks for using this program! Do you want to do it again? (Y or N)");

  if(scan.next().toLowerCase().equals("y")){

    doItAgain = true;
    break;
  } 

  else{

    doItAgain = false;
    System.out.println("If you change your mind and want to run it again, type runMain.");//output closing statement if user says N to restart
    break;
  }
} 
} 
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit your question out like that.  It doesn't make sense for those who may stumble upon it later.

Answer (score 1):

You are not merging your `arrays`. Your 1st `array` is, for instance [1 2] and your second `array` is, for instance [3 4]. Your final array is going to be initialized with size 4 (`first2.length + second2.length`), but all it's elements will be zero.

In this line here, I suggest you use `arraycopy()` to fill your final `array`:

```
int[] array = new int[first2.length + second2.length];

System.arraycopy(first2, 0, array, 0, first2.length);
System.arraycopy(second2, 0, array, first2.length, second2.length);
```

This will copy the `first2` array to the starting position of your final array and then copy your `second2` array to the position of your final array where `first2` ended. You will end up with [1 2 3 4] and can then sort the elements (though in this case, they're already sorted.

For more information on `arraycopy()` consult this page here: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_arraycopy.htm

**EDIT:** BTW, you have an error right here, which is what is preventing you from printing the full sorted array:

```
//output sorted merged array
System.out.println("\nMerged Array: ");
for(int p3 = 0; p3<array.length; p3++) {
    System.out.print(array[p3] + " ");
} //right here, you need to close this curly bracket
```

**EDIT2:** Since you can't use `arraycopy()`, you can use `for` loops to fill in the final array:

```
for(int k = 0; k <first2.length;k++){
    array[k] = first2[k];
}

for (int l = 0; l<second2.length;l++){
    array[first2.length + l] = second2[l];
}
```

Comment: @JohnHughes Simply use a `for` loop to replace the `0`'s of your final array with the elements from your other two arrays (`first2` and `second2`).

Comment: @JohnHughes The 4 zeros are technically correct, since that is your final array. Use the `for` loops I mentioned and it will work fine. The "Yes Restart", you'll have to work around.

Comment: @JohnHughes Well, where do you think you need to put it in order to fill in the final array? For how would these `for` loops look like, look at my EDIT2. Also, I recommend you read `arraycopy()` documentation to understand how this process works.

Comment: That is a whole different question. I would suggest you try and do it for yourself now. Take a look at some easy sorting algorithms like Bubble sort and try to implement them.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use bubble sort. I posted my updated code to sort but only partially works. What am I missing?

Comment: @JohnHughes I know you're not allowed to use sorts, that's why I'm recommending you to "implement" Bubble sort.

Comment: I am also not allowed to use bubble sorting since we haven't learnt that in class. I posted my updated code and it it partly sorted for only one array. How would I sort the whole thing?

Comment: @John Hughes In case you still haven't figured out, you need to sort `array3` not `first2` and `second2`.  Right here, `//sort array 3`, change your condition of `i<first2.length + 1` to `i<array.length`. Same goes for the second `for` loop.

Comment: Yea I figured it out before. Thanks so much for your input!!